# ZingChart - Different colors for text in crosshair

Tags: charts, zingchart

If we specify the content of crosshairX in the 'plotarea' attribute, by default the color of whole text becomes black. I want to represent this text of crosshair in two different colors. For example, suppose my text is "2016 : 0.07 M", then '2016' should appear in blue color and '0.07 M' in red.
How can we achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Full Disclosure, I'm a member of the ZingChart team.

I would need to know how you are displaying your text to have a more specific solution. Are you using the default plotLabel.text or do you have a user defined plotLabel.text? If so what is it set to?

Without knowing what you have defined for text I have taking the liberty to put together a demo of the different combinations of applying colors and text to a [plotLabel](https://www.zingchart.com/docs/json-attributes-syntax/crosshair/plot-label/).

There are a couple things happening here:

- headerText is defining its text color as grey
- the first span tag in text is inheriting the plot color with %color
- the second span tag in text is defining its text color as black
- the plotLable.color attribute is red making all other text outside of the span tags red

```js
var myConfig = {
  type: "line",
  scaleX:{
    values:['Mon','Tue','Wed','Th','Fri','Sat','Sun']
  },
  crosshairX:{
    plotLabel:{
      headerText:'<span style="color:#777">Header Text</span>',
      text:'<span style="color:%color">%kv</span>: <span style="color:black">%v</span> Extra Text...',
      color:'red'
    }
  },
 series : [
  {
   values : [35,42,67,89,25,34,67]
  },
  {
   values : [35,42,67,89,25,34,67].sort()
  }
 ]
};

zingchart.render({ 
 id : 'myChart', 
 data : myConfig, 
 height: 350, 
 width: '100%' 
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
 <!--Assets will be injected here on compile. Use the assets button above-->
  <script src= "https://cdn.zingchart.com/zingchart.min.js"></script>
  <script> zingchart.MODULESDIR = "https://cdn.zingchart.com/modules/";</script>
 <!--Inject End-->
 </head>
 <body>
  <div id='myChart'></div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks @nardecy. This is exactly what I wanted to achieve. Zingchart is good :-)